# Export all contents of "Device Manager"

Tags: windows-7, device-manager

How could I export all the contents of **Device Manager** to an `.xml` file or any other format which can show me the hierarchy and all properties there ?

I could not find any idea except *print screen*  .

Comment: Should this be built-in tool or free 3rd party tool which requires no installation is acceptable as well?

Comment: 3rd party tool is also acceptable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getxmlin.cmd

```
SET msinfo32="%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\MSInfo\msinfo32.exe"
%msinfo32% /nfo hwdres.nfo /categories +resources
rename hwdres.nfo hwdres.xml
```

list categories, need run Help and Support service:

```
msinfo32 /showcategories
```

DevCon is included in the WDK in the %WindowsSdkDir%\tools\x64 and the %WindowsSdkDir%\tools\x86

```
DEVCON findall *
```

Output:

```
V1394\NIC1394\1B9E0F31E8C00                                 : 1394 Net Adapter
{C3D35B99-3000-4F04-BC44-FD0B32F29A6D}\GENERICMOUNTDEVICE\1&224BCE6C&1&GENERICMOUNTDEVICE4: Generic Mount Device
510 matching device(s) found.
```

neet XSLT, txt -> xml;

class category DEVCON

```
DEVCON findall =Net
```

Comment: can you give some more explanation here please ?

Comment: @URL87 Tell me, what exactly is necessary to explain, and I'll do it with pleasure.

Comment: What is mean  - `getxmlin.cmd` ? And where should I see the texts you write in `  ` section  ?

Comment: @URL87 `getxmlin.cmd` - batch file, the text is below, the following three lines. If you do not like the name, you can change it.) Output - can be viewed in `cmd` or any other shell, such as Far Manager.

Comment: A very simplified explanation in case someone doesn't understand this answer: Usually it should be enough to enter into the command prompt (including the quotation marks): "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSInfo\msinfo32.exe" /nfo hwdres.nfo /categories +resources     That creates the file "C:\Windows\System32\hwdres.nfo", which is an xml file. If you have Notepad++ (or something similar), you can already open the file, otherwise you have to change the file extension from "nfo" to "xml".

Comment: Ok, the file is in the directory that you are executing the command from, not always in C:\Windows\System32.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at [WinAudit](https://winaudit.codeplex.com/)

Here are some main features:

- *No setup*
- *Csv/html/pdf/xml*
- *Command line*
- *free*

You can audit only H/W (`Options` button)and export in xml only this info.
On the right-pane on the screen-shot is detailed info about particular device.

Hierarchy structure is preserved if printed to `.PDF` and `.HTML` formats,
but doesn't seem to be true for `.XML`.

`.PDF` looks to be the perfect variant.

[image: WinAudit]